# C++ "does not name a type" - unable to compile source files

Tags: c++, compilation, header-files

I'm trying to compile my code and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I believe it could be the order of my compilation, but I can't figure out my mistake.

My error code:

```
g++ -w -c JokeServer.cpp
In file included from JokeServer.h:4:0,
                 from JokeServer.cpp:52:
AdminServer.h:9:2: error: ‘JokeServer’ does not name a type
make: *** [JokeServer.o] Error 1
```

Thank you.

JokeServer.h file:

```
#ifndef JOKESERVER_H
#define JOKESERVER_H

#include "AdminServer.h"
#include "Subject.h"
#include "Observer.h"
#include "Worker.h"

class JokeServer: public Subject {
private:
    AdminServer* m_admin_server;

public:
     //public functions
};

#endif
```

AdminServer.h file:

```
#ifndef ADMINSERVER_H
#define ADMINSERVER_H

#include "JokeServer.h"
#include "AdminWorker.h"

class AdminServer {
private:
    JokeServer* m_joke_server;

public:
  //public functions        
};

#endif
```

My make file:

```
CPPFLAGS = g++ -w

all: JokeServer JokeClient AdminClient

#-------------------------------------
# JOKE SERVER
#-------------------------------------
JokeServer: JokeServer.o Worker.o JokeGenerator.o ProverbGenerator.o AdminServer.o AdminWorker.o
    $(CPPFLAGS) JokeServer.o Worker.o JokeGenerator.o ProverbGenerator.o AdminServer.o AdminWorker.o -o JokeServer -lpthread

JokeServer.o: JokeServer.cpp JokeServer.h Subject.h
    $(CPPFLAGS) -c JokeServer.cpp

Worker.o: Worker.cpp Worker.h Observer.h
    $(CPPFLAGS) -c Worker.cpp

JokeGenerator.o: JokeGenerator.cpp JokeGenerator.h
    $(CPPFLAGS) -c JokeGenerator.cpp

ProverbGenerator.o: ProverbGenerator.cpp ProverbGenerator.h
    $(CPPFLAGS) -c ProverbGenerator.cpp

AdminServer.o: AdminServer.cpp AdminServer.h
    $(CPPFLAGS) -c AdminServer.cpp

AdminWorker.o: AdminWorker.cpp AdminWorker.h
    $(CPPFLAGS) -c AdminWorker.cpp
```

Comment: how about the cpp files?

Comment: You need to make a *minimal* example that shows your problem. There are files you've not shown here, but already it's too long as a Stack Overflow question. Probably you need to forward declare one or more types in your headerfiles since they reference each other a lot though. (I.e. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/forward-decl.html but across files)

Comment: You have a circular dependency between `AdminServer.h` and `JokeServer.h`. There are plenty of SO questions on this.

Comment: Does your compiler have an option to be more helpful about the line it complains about?

Comment: You have header files that include each other. What do you expect to happen when the preprocessor expands them for compilation? Which lines should be in the resulting file and in what order? Use `-E` compilation flag to ask the preprocessor what *it* thinks it should do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a **cyclic reference** between your `.h` files. Files `AdminServer.h` and `JokeServer.h` include each other. You should use forward declarations to solve this problem.

For instance, in `JokeServer.h`:

```
#ifndef JOKESERVER_H
#define JOKESERVER_H

// REMOVE THIS
// #include "AdminServer.h"

// ADD THIS
class AdminServer;
```

Also notice, that all the files that were *indirectly* including `AdminServer.h` by including `JokeServer.h` (for instance, I suspect, `JokeServer.cpp`) will have to include `AdminServer.h` to access the definition of class `AdminServer`

Comment: Thanks Andy, that worked. This is my first time encountering cyclic reference,I'll remember this for future.

Comment: @Gene: I understand, circular dependencies of headers result in odd compilation errors, and the first time you create one it is hard to figure out what's going on. too bad *modules* are not supported by C++ yet.